# Почему сессия не уничтожается?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь понять сессии в php. Прописал в .htaccess

```
# Время жизни сессии в секундах
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10
# Время жизни куки в секундах
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 10
```

Еще взял код [отсюда](https://coder-booster.ru/learning/php-practice/create-and-delete-sessions)

```
<?php
//если пользователь не будет 10 секунд посылать запросы
//на сервер, его сессия будет автоматически удалена
session_start(['gc_maxlifetime' => 10]);

echo 'php version = '.phpversion().'<br>';
echo 'gc_maxlifetime = '.ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime').'<br>';
echo 'cookie_lifetime = '.ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime').'<br>';

if (isset($_SESSION['isStarted'])) {
    $difference = time() - $_SESSION['startTime'];
    echo "От старта сессии прошло {$difference}сек";

} else {
    $_SESSION = [
        'isStarted' => true,
        'startTime' => time()
    ];

    echo 'Создана новая сессия';
}
?>
```

Не отправляю запрос более 10 секунд, закрываю браузер. Но сессия все равно живет. Почему?

Comment: Перед тем, как пробовать уничтожающуюся сессию, вы удаляли старые долгоживущие сессии, почистив куки в браузере?

Comment: Я ничего не удалял. Разве куки не должны удалятся сами?

Comment: Те куки, которые были созданы **до того**, как вы прописали 10 секунд, конечно не будут удаляться, потому что 10 секунд это только для новых кук. Удалите старые куки в браузере и попробуйте ещё раз, вдруг причина в этом

Comment: @andreymal хорошо. Вроде помогло. Можете оформить как ответ.